# what are the minimum privileges a user needs in MySQL to use the replace command?

Tags: mysql, privileges

The title is basically the question; what are the minimum privileges a MySQL user needs to use the `REPLACE` command? My initial guess is `SELECT`, `DELETE`, and `INSERT`, but I want to make sure that the user doesn't need `UPDATE` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

> To use REPLACE, you must have both the INSERT and DELETE privileges for the table.

Comment: Thanks; I completely missed that in my reading of the documentation.